# Alternative to is_dir

Tags: php

I created a script that would check certain folders located in a **Network folder** on Windows (Both the server and the client are on Windows).

Now when using `is_dir` sometimes it gives true and sometimes it gives false for different folders. I am Interested in the false ones, because I checked the URL manually and it does exist.

**Notes:**

1. I used the absolute path to check the folders.
2. I am using Wamp Server with PHP 5.4.
3. I have full permissions to access all the folders on the Network.

### UPDATE

The example I am working on is this:
I have a list of clients stored in the database. Each client has a folder in a **Network folder (Clients)** which is managed by a domain controller, and each client folder has a standard folder structure:

```
Client 1
|--Folder A
|--Folder B
|--Folder C

Client 2
|--Folder A
|--Folder B
|--Folder C
```

The code iterates over the clients and check for example if **Folder A** exists.

```
// $clients is an array of names.
foreach($clients as $client)
{
    if(is_dir("\\\\MyDomain\\Clients\\{$client}\\Folder A"))
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Now the previous code sometimes work and sometimes returns false even if the folder actually exists in the Clients folder.

As for Wamp permissions, I tried two different users which have permissions to access to the **Clients** folder and each Client sub-folder, and both gave the same result. As I said before, sometimes `is_dir` returns `true` and sometimes returns `false`.

[image]

Comment: Please show us your code. Also you're free to add a question to this post

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: Please share your code, I suspect your not supplying it with the full/correct path.

Comment: `is_dir` will return false when no execute rights are granted for the php user

Answer (score 0):

I guess WAMP is running as a service. find out with what credentials this service starts ( Run as administrator: services.msc ) and make sure that THIS user got the rights to open/read the related directories.

when using a website it is not your logon user account that is requesting to list or check for a directory (even if server and browser are on the same machine), but it's the web-server searching for you. It's him who needs the rights to read.